# Apply Singular Value Decomposition on Gabor filters

Tags: image-processing, matlab, filtering, gabor

According to my question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210307/working-on-separable-gabor-filters-in-matlab), I applied (with a big help from lennon310) the separability of Gabor filters of any orientation.
The only disadvantage of this method is the convolution in the complex domain. So we can treat  the Gabor ﬁlter `G(x,y)` as a two dimensional matrix that has a low rank, since the ﬁlter is fairly smooth at lower frequencies. Singular value decomposition can then be used in order to decompose the ﬁlter into a linear sum of real separable ﬁlters.

[image]

Here, `ui`, `vi` are the columns of the orthogonal matrices `U,V`. `s_i` is the singular value. The convolution of the ﬁlter `G(x, y)` with the image `I(x, y)` can now be approximated using:
[image]

Please I need a help about how can I edit my code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210307/working-on-separable-gabor-filters-in-matlab) in order to apply that in MATLAB. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't recommend you apply SVD in your Gabor filter, since it does not bring much benefit but increase the computing load. If you implement SVD, you may not separate the filter at first, instead the SVD is performed on the [2D Gabor filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921698/how-to-create-64-gabor-features-at-each-scale-and-orientation-in-the-spatial-and):

```
                for i = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR
                    for j = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR

                        if ( sqrt(i^2+j^2)>filtSize/2 )
                            E = 0;
                        else
                            x = i*cos(theta) - j*sin(theta);
                            y = i*sin(theta) + j*cos(theta);
                            E = exp(-(x^2+G^2*y^2)/(2*sigmaq))*cos(2*pi*x/lambda(k));
                        end
                        f(j+center,i+center) = E;
                    end
                end

               %% SVD %%%%
               [u,s,v]=SVD(f);
```

With `u`, `s`, and `v`, you implement the convolution with your image:

```
    convv = zeros(size(image_double));
    for i = 1:filtSizeR+filtSizeL+1
        convv1=imfilter(image_double*s(i,i),  u(i,:),'conv');
        convv2=imfilter(double(convv1),v(:,i)','conv');
        convv = convv + convv2;
    end

    figure
    imagesc(imag(convv));
```

Yet I don't think this method is as good as your separable `f` and `g` method.

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for your response! Ok so you applied firstly the SVD, but what is the T in USV (shown in the formula of my question) ?.advance!

Comment: T is the transpose symbol, I used v(:,i)' in the code

Comment: And please can you tell me why you took K as i=1:filtSizeR+filtsizeL+1 ? ah what is the difference between v(i,:) and v(:.i) ? finally, in the paper, they demonstrated that this method is more optimal than separable Gabor in terms of time complexity, so what is your opinion :)

Comment: for i = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR means the size of f is filtSizeR+filtsizeL+1. v(i,:) is the ith row of v, and v(:,i)' is the ith row of v'. I don't think svd is better in time complexity, even if it is, the space complexity is very high: if size(f) is large, svd will be very slow, or even cannot finish due to OUT OF MEMORY error

Comment: But in the paper, they told that K is <4, so in your code, firstly K is equal to 7, secondly to 9 etc. ?

Comment: they select the first K singular values to approximate the equation. You can also use for i=1:K in the loop after svd

Comment: Okay Thank you so much. You are really an expert:) Que dios te bendiga!!:):)

Comment: you are very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

**The final code will be:**

```
for i = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR
            for j = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR

                if ( sqrt(i^2+j^2)>filtSize/2 )
                    E = 0;
                else
                    x = i*cos(theta) - j*sin(theta);
                    y = i*sin(theta) + j*cos(theta);

                     %fx = exp(-(i^2)/(2*sigmaq))*exp(sqrt(-1)*i*cos(theta));
                     %gy = exp(-(j^2)/(2*sigmaq))*exp(sqrt(-1)*j*sin(theta));
                     %E=real(fx*gy);

                   E = exp(-(x^2+G^2*y^2)/(2*sigmaq))*cos(2*pi*x/lambda(k));
                end
                f(j+center,i+center) = E;
            end
        end

        f = f - mean(mean(f));
        f = f ./ sqrt(sum(sum(f.^2)));

%%%% SVD %%%%
        [u,s,v]=svd(f);

 convv = zeros(size(image_double));
   for i = 1:filtSizeR+filtSizeL+1
       convv1=imfilter(image_double*s(i,i),  u(i,:),'conv');
        convv2=imfilter(double(convv1),v(:,i)','conv');
        convv = convv + convv2;
    end

    figure
    imagesc(convv);
    colormap(gray);
```

Comment: looks good to me :)